# How to configure 2nd network card for use in VMWare Workstation?

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation, network-adapter

I am using VMWare Workstation 6.5, connected to my network with a bridged adapter so that the virtual machine OS (Windows XP) has its own IP address. This just worked out of the box.

Now my host machine (Windows Vista) has an additional network card that is directly connected to another computer using a crossover cable (and fixed IP address `10.1.1.4`, while the "main" network connection is using DHCP with IP in the `192.68.0.*` range).

How can I use that network connection as well in the virtual machine?
Do I need to bridge my 2nd network adapter to some VMnetX adapter?
Do I need to add a host virtual adapter?

I do not know much about networks, and the VMWare network settings really confuse me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create a second bridged virtual network adapter pointing to the second card and add it to the Virtual Machine. However you may need to give this a static IP if it is on Crossover since there will not be a DHCP server available from your current configuration.

Comment: I set up one VM adapter normally (bridged, DHCP, on the host's "primary" port).  The other I set up bridged, to the host's "alternate" port, with a static IP address and no gateway.  Seems to work as I intended.