# Assign second physical ethernet port to VM

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, network-adapter

I have a motherboard with two physical ethernet ports. Obviously, my computer is connected to my network by one of them.
Is it possible to dedicate the other one to a virtual machine so that it is seen as a separate (physical) machine on my network?

An answer specific to VMware is preferred but a general one would be fine too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/23644/how-to-configure-2nd-network-card-for-use-in-vmware-workstation

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new Network Adapter in Virtual Machine Settings set the Type of the adapter to custom and configure it to Bridge in Virtual Network Editor. From that screen you can specify what physical adapter do you want to use.