# VMware WorkStation Server change NIC

Tags: vmware-workstation

I have installed a 10Gb NIC in my workstation server and I share the VM's on the network. When accessing the server from another workstation I'm currently forced to use the onboard NIC addresses to connect to it. In the sharing preferences of workstation server it only allows the option to change the port.

Is it possible to change the server to point to the other NIC and not the onboard one?

Host server has 2 NICS

- onboard connects to router and provides internet.
- PCIe 10Gb connects directly to client system.

Client system has 2 NICS

- onboard connects to router and provides internet.
- PCIe 10Gb connects directly to server system.

When connecting to the host server via vmware Workstation share, I can currently only provide the address for the onboard NIC to access the shares. When providing the 10Gb address, the connection is refused. This is because the vmware workstation server defaults to the onboard NIC.

I am trying to configure the host server to accept a connection via vmware workstation to allow the 10Gb NIC's address.

Is this possible?

Comment: Looks to be already answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/23644/how-to-configure-2nd-network-card-for-use-in-vmware-workstation

Comment: That question refers to accessing the virtual machines on the second NIC. I am trying to connect to the server (shared VM's) via the second NIC.

Comment: "Is it possible to change the server to point to the other NIC and not the onboard one?" - Yes;  Lots of servers have multiple network cards.  There simply isn't enough information about your setup to determine the reason you are unable to connect to your server using your 10 GB network card though.

Comment: I've added more details.